# (background) push notification, and built on phonegap build for android/iphone

Tags: cordova

Is there a push notification plugin/approach for phonegap (android/iphone) where:

1. the application can still be built using phonegap build.
2. the push notification can be received even when the application is not running (in the foreground)

I am trying HARD not do manage separate Android (Java) and iPhone (Xcode) projects.

If not, what would be the easiest way to implement this for BOTH android & iphone? Urban Airship looks very close to doing this (not sure if can be built via phonegap build though).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently what you describe here is not yet available with phonegap build. You need to use cordova (=phonegap) plugins for that and currently only one plugin is supported by phonegap build (see [Supported plugins](https://build.phonegap.com/docs/plugins) ).

If you want something quickly you'll have to do with your own custom builds. Have a look at [this repository of plugins](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins). You'll see two Push plugins: PushNotification and UAPushNotification they seem to be both using Urban Airship integration.

To reply to your second question, it does look like the push notifications are only visible once your application starts, not when it's stopped.

Comment: Thanks for the response. It seems almost defeating the purpose of "notifications" if the app needs to be "started" to receive them no? BTW, "start" means running in foreground or not really?

Comment: From what I've seen it looks like it's when the application is started or is becoming active (background to foreground).

Answer (score 1):

I'm also looking at implementing a solution down this path for both Android and iOS (and possibly WP).

Testing so far with Android only, it seems that [Pushwoosh](http://www.pushwoosh.com/) seems like it can sort-of do what we're looking for.

I haven't tested it with iPhone yet but, with Android, the application be in background, the phone receives a push notification giving a notification in the status bar of the phone.  Tapping on this notification opens the app and you can access data from within the notification at this time.

One limitation I've come up against is that there is no way to access push notification data upon receipt of notification from within PhoneGap app.  Only when the notification is tapped (which means clearing notifications or even receiving a second notification for same app means you lose that data forever).  Theoretically, this should be possible but the code for this is likely hidden away within the Pushwoosh.jar file.

Answer (score 0):

It is now possible to have push notifications received and accessed via a plugin compatible with PhoneGap build.

https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin